# How to load mouse driver/support in text tty terminals (Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6])?

Tags: command-line

I launch some text mode program (which accepts mouse input, like MC...) in text terminal and want to be able to use my mouse.

Is there some command I should enter to enable mouse support in this text terminals?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gpm
```

and reboot

and then it will work

As of 12.04.3 there is no need to reboot.

Comment: "service gpm start" may be necessary.