# How to save the contents of unlogged console screen to a file?

Tags: command-line, server, tty

I'm on a tty, with a lots of command inputs, bulk of verbose their output, and some error messages. Now I have to get all those stdin/stdout/stderr texts, in the format displayed in the console screen, dumped to a file. How can I get that done using the inbuilt tools (preferably)?

I don't know if the question is confusing! It's really a simple one.. Suppose I logged into tty1 console terminal, ran some commands (with no logging enabled, because I didn't feel the need to) but suddenly there came certain outputs/messages that I want to dump into a file (or the other option get a pen and a paper).

The reason why I am assuming this could be done is because you can use the `shift + PgUp/PgDwn` to shift the screen outputs, which means they are still there in the buffer (even if the processing is pipelined)! ..and that is what should be recovered.

Comment: Why don't you use redirection?

Comment: It's not about redirecting the output of some commands but it's about dumping the contents of entire session.. the inputs, outputs and error messages.. yes I can always use redirection in cases I know I need them in advance, but the Q is for the other case.. while using terminal emulator in GUI session I could just copy the contents and save them to a file, but it doesn't seem to be that easy in the mouseless world of tty..

Comment: [this answer on AU](http://askubuntu.com/a/161946/184942) may be useful.Also read [this post on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111572).Finally, have a look at [google search results](https://www.google.co.in/search?&q=creating+log+of+every+output+in+terminal+linux)

Comment: That's nice too, thanks.. But it's not exactly what I want..

Comment: @RegisteredUser I see you included a google for me... But starting a script each time I start a terminal is not the way I want it to be. It should be _post-jobs and not pre-jobs_, if you get what I mean..

Comment: as a correction update to my earlier comment, I attach this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77473/how-to-load-mouse-driver-support-in-text-tty-terminals-ctrlaltf1-6) which mentions the daemon `gpm`, I've not tested it myself but the console needn't always be mouseless.

Comment: AFAIK linux works with pipelines for data processing.If you want to log data, it should be piped in real time. I don't think post-job logging is possible, except manual copy-pasting. You may have some luck with finding a tool that would copy paste data from tty/terminal-emu to a file, though I think such a tool doesn't exist.

Comment: yeah with pseudo terms like gnome-terminal that's how I used to do it, copy and paste.. but in tty there should be a way.. like you point as long as they are in the display they should be buffered somewhere temporarily and that should not only be retrieved but also in a well formatted form..

Comment: What about http://serverfault.com/questions/526294/how-to-grab-either-bash-history-or-last-x-number-lines-from-shell-process-runnin?

Comment: that seem to display the feeds and outputs at two different terminals..?! I don't know.. I am looking to get every thing that was on my term screen before a point of time..

Answer (score 7):

TTYs use "virtual console memory" devices to buffer their screen content. You can read more about them in `man vcs` but **this will let you get what is on the screen at the current moment**.

In practise these are just numbered files in `/dev/` that line up with the TTY number. Here's an example I did with TTY2:

```
$ sudo fold -w$(stty -F /dev/tty2 size | awk '{print $2}') /dev/vcs2

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS bert tty2                                                      

bert login: oli                                                                 
Password:                                                                       
oli@bert:~$ cd test                                                             
oli@bert:~/test$ ls                                                             
Madonna - 10 - Bedtime Story.mp3  output_MP3WRAP.mp3                            
Madonna - 11 - Take A Bow.mp3                                                   
oli@bert:~/test$
```

The `fold -w$(...)` there is because the buffered output doesn't *appear* to have the control characters or newlines I would expect. This simply adds `\n` at the end of every line.

As TuKsn points out in the comments, you don't have to mess around with all this, you can achieve exactly the same with:

```
sudo screendump 2
```

You can stick `> tty.log` on the end of either command to write the output to a file called `tty.log` in the current directory:

```
sudo screendump 2 > tty.log
```

---

Again, **this will only get you what is on the screen**. Even if you increase the scrollback buffer in TTYs, [this isn't stored in accessible memory](https://serverfault.com/a/122295/2619). You [can alter that](https://superuser.com/questions/188993/increase-linux-terminal-scrollback-buffer-size) but that involves recompiling the kernel.

That would involve rebooting and losing the *current* screen so if you can do that there are much easier options for logging *future* IO, like `screen` or `tmux` or just `script`.

Comment: is there a memory limit to vcs? In the GUI I've set the terminal profile to use unlimited scroll, but that doesn't seem to apply in the ttys!

Comment: If i use `sudo fold -w$(stty -F /dev/tty2 size | awk '{print $2}') /dev/vcs2`  or [sudo screendump](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/SCREENDUMP/) (should be the same) there are only a limited output of the last commands (64 lines?), seems to be there is a memory limit.

Comment: +1 for `fold` and `screendump` which does the work but leaves it incomplete, just dumps the last screen.. (and yes, I too liked `script` but my display seems to be flicker with the `screen` on)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use a program named `screen`. It saves all output of Terminal into a file. Have a look at this Ubuntu Forums thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1379903. CMIIW.

Comment: If I have to trigger the log-process at the start there's [`script`](http://askubuntu.com/a/161946/212123) as suggested by @registered-user above..

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot find any keyboard shortcut for Select All, I have found these that might help... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536757/selecting-text-in-terminal-without-using-the-mouse
[A command-line clipboard copy and paste utility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility)

The first one is screen, which has been suggested, but it seems to have a utility that copies text, so that might work.
Enter copy mode with ^A-Esc. Start selecting text with space and end selecting text with space. Insert text with ^A-]

The second one is about pasting the text in the Clipboard to a file. I am completely unsure if any of these will work though... Hope one does.